# Add Line in Sandcastle generated example code

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, sandcastle, xml-comments

I want to add a line in Sandcastle generated example code
This is what i have written so far

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the SQL Connection for interaction with the Database
/// </summary>
/// <example> Add these lines in the Web.config or App.config File. 
/// Value here should be the Active Database Context
/// <code>
/// <appSettings>
/// <add key= "DBName" value="ActiveDBContext"/>
/// </appSettings>
/// </code>
/// </example>
public class DataConnection : IDisposable
{
   // rest of the class here
}
```

but in the sandcastle generated documentation file, it displays like this

```
<appSettings><add key="DBName" value="ActiveDBContext" /></appSettings>
```

where as I want it to get displayed like this

```
<appSettings>
   <add key= "DBName" value="AssetCaptureDB"/>
</appSettings>
```

I guess it is because of the < & > characters, How can I add a line break to the documentation file where these characters are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
/// <code><![CDATA[<appSettings>
///    <add key= "DBName" value="AssetCaptureDB"/>
/// </appSettings>]]></code>
```

I didn't try it with Sandcastle, but with [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) (which is our product) it worked fine. The comment was generated with VSdocman's comment editor.